# my invite request does not shown to target friend

Tags: facebook, request, facebook-opengraph, invite, facebook-requests

first of all, sorry to my poor english.
I m try to integrate with facebook and my game on android. but i have met a problem.
i have sent a invite request to my friend. and response is ok.
but it seems like not actually working. target friend can't see the invite request.
It's same Whether app is sandbox mode or not.

my code is below :

```
private static void doRequestInvite() {
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "Let's play together");

WebDialog requestsDialog = (
    new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder( activity, Session.getActiveSession(), params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {

                if( toastFeedback) {
                    if (error != null) {
                        if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            Toast.makeText( activity.getApplicationContext(), "Request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText( activity.getApplicationContext(), "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                        if (requestId != null) {
                            Toast.makeText( activity.getApplicationContext(), "OK to invite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText( activity.getApplicationContext(), "Request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .build();
requestsDialog.show();      
}


public static void requestInvite() {
...  
// this is not main UI thread. but web dialog must be run on main UI thread
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doRequestInvite();
    }
});
}
```

what can i do for check this? please give some hint.

Comment: Where do you get toastFeedback from?

Comment: Though from this code: if runOnUiThread and doRequestInvite both run fine (the dialog shows as it should, etc.) and you get a "OK to invite", i don't really see why the request wouldn't be received (this seems to be straight from the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests/), correct?).

Comment: i got messag a "OK to invite". toastFeedback is static value is set true.

Comment: it's my profile. https://www.facebook.com/ozlael.oz

Comment: open graph request has same problem. you can see the result on my "recently". "Ozlael sent a energy *** on RunAndDish." but target friend never see that message

Comment: Weird... Make the voids non-static :P(kidding, doubt it's really relevant)? Perhaps there is a problem with the api integration itself. You're using adt, correct, what debugging have you tried, did you review the requests themselves? I don't really have a Facebook account so can't actually test any of this myself, sorry :(... Perhaps try posting on android dev forums. What version are you using?

Comment: As i said the problem doesn't seem to be caused by the code you've posted so it's probably something else.

Comment: thanks a lot. I agree with Mr. Denche. I use facebook SDK V3.0. It's stable version.... T_T I have sent Invite Request and Open Graph Story to about 10 friends many times. but they did not receive messages except one person. but that person got only a Invite Request at one time. Open Graph was not received.  what can i do for check this?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone happens to read this thread, I think the problem is that apparently you need to have a `Canvas Page` in order for the notifications to appear. Otherwise they will only be shown on `AppCenter` in the `Request` tab.

However, even if you set up a Canvas Page, I'm not sure how to modify the message of the notification.

Comment: For invites the message is not shown by Facebook deliberately.